# Amazon command line tool http error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mechanicalturk

I have amazon command line tool to post HITs to Mturk. But there seems to be a problem with the mturk URL in mturk.properties. It keeps asking for https.

I searched for the solution in aws forums, with most stating simply change the URL from http to https. I have tried and get the following error

> An error occurred while fetching your balance: >javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: HTTPS hostname invalid: expected >'176.32.98.23', received 'mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com'